# Flutter Can We obtain any IOS Device Information?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm making an app where I had to obtain device's information. Works well on Android but can't seem to get anything from IOS device. Is there any other package for that? Or can we not obtain anything anymore from IOS Device?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus), it's worked for me.